# Client-side Twitter API method using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, twitter, client-side

Does (or did) Twitter ever have a method in their API that allowed client-side HTTP requests without producing any cross-domain issues? I have a site that used the following url:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3adaleyjem&rpp=3&page=1&callback=?

It once worked, but now it doesn't.

Is there something else I should be using, or do I have to make a request to my own server-side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I figured out that while this might not be the solution for each person's special case, I ended up doing a  tag include with a callback at the end of the URL... like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/daleyjem.json?callback=showTwitter&count=1"></script>
```

And then just created a function called "showTwitter"